# grails rendering plugin not rendering GSP tags or HTML form elements to PDF

Tags: pdf, grails, plugins, rendering

I am using the grails rendering plugin `v1.0.0` (https://grails.org/plugin/rendering) together with grails(`v2.5.1`) and the pdf generation does not work neither for the gsp's or the HTML components like checkboxes, textfields etc.. although for a basic text structured with a div components it renders a pdf and allows me to style it with css.. but I want to use i18n tags like g:message and then make things more complicated to solve..

Is there any reason for this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your code here ?